# how to run command line python scripts within my code

Tags: python

there are some scripts that you have to run them from command line like

`python run.py -u alex__a -p 123 -v -f`

I want to work with them inside my code I don't know whats the name of them so I wasn't able to google about my question . sorry if it't so simple

Comment: os.system('python run.py -u alex__a -p 123 -v -f')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `sys.argv` to access them.  Here is a tutorial:

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

If you want to get more serious and use a package to do this more elegantly, you should research the `argparse` package which is excellent and very intuitive to use.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but I'm pretty sure OP is asking how to run an external cli script in their python script.

Comment: Good point!  "Work with them" is pretty ambiguous.  If I'm off target, the comment above about using system to run them internally should scratch the itch.

Comment: no this is not what I want . I don't want to make a command line script . I want to run it inside my code

Comment: bummer.  Well, you have an option above in the comments.